# C++ Unix domain sockets toolkit

Tags: c++, sockets

I am about to write a very simple toolkit, in C++, for Unix domain socket IPC.

Are there any open source ones that people have used with good experience? If not, as consumers of such toolkit, what functionality/interface would one expect from it?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: There is already good support in `boost::asio`, if you think that this is not sufficient, why not contribute to that?

Comment: "Transmission of file descriptors or credentials across UNIX domain sockets is not directly supported within Boost.Asio, but may be achieved by accessing the socket's underlying descriptor using the native() member function." It seems to need some attention. Also see unixman83's [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799692/has-anyone-done-a-performance-analysis-of-boostasio)

Answer (score 1):

The Boost.Asio library already [provides support](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html) for Unix domain sockets.