# What are the biggest differences between boost.asio and the current networking TS?

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, boost, boost-asio

The C++ committee is currently working on a [Networking Technical Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4588.pdf). I was wondering what were the biggest differences with `boost::asio`. Moreover, I heard several times that the [udp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799692/has-anyone-done-a-performance-analysis-of-boostasio#9363356) implementation in `boost::asio` is not as efficient as it could be and I was wondering whether the TS tried to solve this problem.

Comment: regarding the UDP performance; there is no way to send multiple UDP packets in a single call. Not in the networking TS nor in POSIX. This can cause bulk transfers over UDP to be significantly slower and more CPU heavy than over TCP. Linux has an API to do this though (sendmmsg()).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The largest difference is that Networking TS has less stuff: no support for SSL, serial ports, OS signals and other OS-specific things. The TS is still designed to allow users of the library to add these features.

Also, the TSes usually don't delve into implementation details. So you should check with your STL implementation if it has problems you mentioned.