How boost::asio::steady_timer behaves with periods of microseconds?
I want to create boost I/O object that executes few operations concurrently from my program but they shall be executed every 50 microseconds (it is for EtherCAT communication, which is a fast protocol). Is it possible to create timers for this fast transactions in asio? Is it accurate? (I don't care if is CPU demanding)
like:
steady_timer timer{ioservice,std::chrono::microseconds{50}};


What's the target platform? I have to ask because 50 us is a hard thing to get in conventional desktop hardware regardless of what boost can offer.

It's a custom Linux custom light Yocto Image with an CPU isolation for running real time app. I can achieve that using a CPU expensive while to check time change. But it would be nice to use Asio.

If your kernel is rt enhanced you might be able to. So in the end only uses kernel mechanisms. If by processor isolation you mean thread affinity, sounds like you're doing many things right. Remember to disable multitasking support if you don't need it (it removes locking overhead) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72286758/is-it-safe-to-disable-threads-on-boostasio-in-a-multi-threaded-program/72292313#72292313
